# Fetch API "PATCH" request from React to ASP.NET Core 6 Backend API fails

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

I am sending PATCH request from React frontend to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API backend server via fetch API and getting 400 Bad Request as a response. I have wrapper around fetch method for adding additional headers such as authorization or function for refreshing tokens etc. Other HTTP requests such as POST, PUT, GET works correctly.

```
async function customFetch(url: string,  method: RequestType, body?: string) : Promise<Response> {

  const requestHeaders: HeadersInit = new Headers();
    
      if (method == RequestType.Patch)
      {
          requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json-patch+json; charset=UTF-8');
      }


  ... // other code blocks 

  return await fetch(url, {
          body: body,
          method: method,
          headers: requestHeaders
      })
```

This is how I call it inside the component. I have a request handler class which calls the above mentioned method.

```
const response = await requestHandler.sendRequest(config.apiurl, RequestType.Patch, { isActive: false }, id);
```

I am using JSON.stringify on the body. I tried sending the body as json patch op, path but it does not work as well. This is the response I am getting from the server. API Endpoint in Swagger UI works just fine for the PATCH request.

```
{"errors":{"":["The JSON patch document was malformed and could not be parsed."],"patchDocument":["The patchDocument field is required."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-00e44924ab187f4c22fe894139fe2bb5-ac73a46d6b4182e9-00"}
```

This is the controller of the WEB API, however it doesn't trigger debugger therefore I am assuming it throws exception somewhere in the middleware.

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartiallyUpdate(Guid id, JsonPatchDocument<RequestDto> patchDocument)
{
   await _appService.PartiallyUpdateAsync(id, patchDocument);

   return NoContent();
}
```

AppService is where I am checking the business rules thus it isn't relevant here as the code does not reach there.

Do I need npm package for the PATCH requests?

Comment: Can you please also paste aspnet core code here?

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama I edited the post with ASP.NET Core code.

Comment: Do you mean it works well on swagger but not work on your react patch method?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, it works correctly on Swagger and Postman but not through React patch method.

Comment: Why your request method in the component only have "id". But your controller accept 2 params "id" and "patchDocument".

Comment: @Jerry ASP.NET Core gets the id from the url itself, patchDocument is the body of the request. For an example I send a request to address domain:5002/api/endpoint/{id} with the body of the request.

Comment: When you debug the patch request from react are you hitting the asp.net core code or not? Did you check the URL or Patch API whether its correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error comes form the wrong body.
You can check the body data format referencing my working code.
MyWebAPI

```
[ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        Person _defaultPerson = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Jim",
            LastName = "Smith"
        };
        [HttpPatch("api")]
        public Person Patch(JsonPatchDocument<Person> personPatch) 
        {
            personPatch.ApplyTo(_defaultPerson);
            return _defaultPerson;
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

what I'm sending with postman:
[image]
what body is working for javascript:

```
<script>
    fetch('https://localhost:7062/api', {      
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: 
            JSON.stringify([
                {
                    "op": "replace",
                    "path": "/FirstName",
                    "value": "Bob"
                }
        ]) ,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
</script>
```